# Eigenvalues and the effect on a vector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have two semi-positive matrices, $A$ and $B$, that differ in their eigenvalues and eigenvectors. I have a random vector $C$, with non-zero, positive elements sampled from an uniform distribution $]0,1]$. I perform the following operations:

$$D=A\cdot C$$
$$E=B\cdot C$$

Do the eigenvalues (or eigenvalues) of the matrices $A$ and $B$ tell anything about the variance in the elements of $C$?

Thank you so much.